# How do I update data values of figure with a change in time in

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I'm currently trying to draw density heatmap which gets updated in real time. This is the figure and app layout that I've defined.

```
figure = dict({
    "data" : [{"type": 'heatmap',
             "x" : [],
             "y" : []}],
    "layout" : {"xaxis" : [0,255], "yaxis" : [0,255]}
})
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.Div([
        html.H1(children='Sensor Data'),

        html.Div(children='''
            3d Representation.
        '''),

        dcc.Graph(
            id='live-update-graph',
            figure = figure
        ),  
    ]),    
    dcc.Interval(
        id = 'clientside-time',
        interval = 10,
        n_intervals = 0
    )
])
```

This is the callback function which is supposed to update data each time.

```
phase = [i for i in range(256)]
phases = []
cycle = []
phases = phase *5

cycle = [[i] *256 for i in range(5)]
cycle = list(chain.from_iterable(cycle))    

@app.callback(
    Output('live-update-graph', 'extendData'),
    Input('clientside-time', 'n_intervals')
)
def update_store_data(time):
    df = DataFrame(storage[256*time : (time+5) * 256], columns = ['Intensity'] )
    df['Phase'] = phases

    print(time)
    return dict(x = [df['Phase']], y = [df['Intensity']])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

In my theory, list slicing is supposed to get different portion from storage list which has been initialized above. However, I don't see any graphs drawn after running this code. Is this the correct way to update data with a change in time?

Comment: Can you share a more complete example, and what the goal of the code is exactly? The way you're accessing elements from `storage` using `time` you're bound to hit an index out of bounds if you let the app run for a while.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden I'm just trying to plot different portion of storage list as time goes. And yes, I need to set the maximum limit on the index.

Answer (score 1):

From experimenting based on the code you've shown I think the graph not displaying properly has something to do with the `interval` value you chose.

When you set `interval` to `10` it means the callback will be triggered every `10` milliseconds ([source](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/interval)), which is very short.

Increasing the `interval` made data appear in the graph when I tested your code with some dummy data.

**Update**

Also you're using a figure of type `heatmap`, but in your callback you're only returning values for `x` and `y`. So the graph wouldn't show up either way, because not all necessary dimensions of the figure are set.

---

By the way if you you're not satisfied by the refresh rate of 1 second you could also use a [client side callback](https://dash.plotly.com/clientside-callbacks). Also see this nice answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63681810/9098350) for more on `extendData` and client side callbacks.

Comment: Can I know what interval you've tried on your end? I've changed the interval to 1000 which is 1 second. I still don't get any images...

Comment: @Taki I've looked at your code again and I notice now that you're using a heatmap and a heatmap needs also needs a `z` dimension in addition to an `x` and a `y`.